# CodeIgniter $this->input->post() array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very curious on why when I print_r($this->input->post()), it prints an array and then has 1 after it.
This is what it prints:

```
Array ( [username] => lilmousiee [birthdate] => 1992-04-26 [gender] => 1 [password] => 66lah66lab [password2] => 66lah66lab [pin] => 2323 [pin2] => 2323 [email] => mouseywings@live.com [email2] => mouseywings@live.com [region] => 1 [dtype] => air [dname] => Mattyco [dgender] => 1 [terms] => [recaptcha_challenge_field] => 03AHJ_VutHNI6hK3M_trpE-n4Qr9V5wWSH10p8hmQjrYVLeWf65ylIDva5XdH78uGED5KCsMx8tp3FHZ6p1xTllyrdSP7nEbnSILQ9CDqrxoD2pit5o9T9Cowy06_O6XLLM22fvH_5ICqoYrmI-o-P8dGCal0fNKuSohgvFU03FmgbhuYTDjJ_xUA [recaptcha_response_field] => asdfsadf [submit] => Register [search] => [type] => usersitems ) 1
```

Why is it printing that "1" after the array? I do not have one even typed... And there is no input field that does a value of 1 after the register button... And what exactly is the "search" and "type" keys?

The last part of my HTML:

```
    <legend>Terms of Use</legend>
    <div id="terms">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae turpis ut sem tristique luctus. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Mauris laoreet vestibulum aliquam. Ut enim tortor, aliquet at faucibus sed, venenatis eget tellus. Praesent velit nisl, bibendum a dignissim nec, hendrerit non lacus. Fusce dapibus pharetra molestie. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae turpis ut sem tristique luctus. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Mauris laoreet vestibulum aliquam. Ut enim tortor, aliquet at faucibus sed, venenatis eget tellus. Praesent velit nisl, bibendum a dignissim nec, hendrerit non lacus. Fusce dapibus pharetra molestie. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae turpis ut sem tristique luctus. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Mauris laoreet vestibulum aliquam. Ut enim tortor, aliquet at faucibus sed, venenatis eget tellus. Praesent velit nisl, bibendum a dignissim nec, hendrerit non lacus. Fusce dapibus pharetra molestie. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae turpis ut sem tristique luctus. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Mauris laoreet vestibulum aliquam. Ut enim tortor, aliquet at faucibus sed, venenatis eget tellus. Praesent velit nisl, bibendum a dignissim nec, hendrerit non lacus. Fusce dapibus pharetra molestie. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_checkbox(array('name' => 'terms')); ?> Accept Terms of Use
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <?php
          echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key);
        ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php echo print_r($array); ?>

<div class="row clearfix"><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Register'); ?></div>
<? echo form_close(); ?>
```

I'm just having trouble passing $this->input->post() array into a validation function. Here is MY_Form_validation.php in my libraries folder:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    private $post;

    public function __construct($params = array()) {
        foreach($params as $param) {
        parent::__construct($param['config']);
$this->post = $param['post'];
        }

    }
}
```

Is there a reason that "1" is being printed as the $this->post value... When it should hold the key and values of the array?
This is how I'm passing the parameters:

```
$this->load->library('MY_Form_validation', array('config' => '', 'post' => $this->input->post()));
```

But when I put print_r($this->post), it only prints "1"..

Comment: Why don't you use `var_dump` to get better variable representations and not worry about it?

Comment: I need to get the values of the recaptcha posted data.. How would I go about doing that/ That's why I was wondering what was passing in the array..

Comment: Read documetation. It is mentioned in bold letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$this->input->post()` is an object and not a string or an array. It's printing out 1 because the object exists and has properties. If it did not exist or was empty, it would print 0. It's just a numerical representation of the boolean return value.

As someone mentioned, if you do `var_dump($this->input->post())` you won't have the "1" character showing up.

To get the value of a field, specify the fieldname in the parentheses:

```
$recaptcha_data = $this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field');
```

Another clarification; You can use `$this->input->post()`'s return value like this:

```
if ($this->input->post()) 
{
    // do stuff if post array exists
}
```

Comment: Then how do I get the array of posted data??? I need to get the recaptcha field value of what the user typed in it..

Answer (score 1):

This is because of you used

```
<?php echo print_r($array); ?>
```

print_r() will print the array and it will return 1.
Echo will display this 1 after printing the array
 you can use just

```
<?php print_r($array); ?>
```

Comment: If you need to use echo (so the print_r output appears when you want, add a second parameter "TRUE". That will make the print_r return the output as a string rather then just dumping it to the output.